# NGinx location directive with Regex

Tags: regex, nginx, redirect, proxy, load-balancing

I'm looking for a way to get my NGinx LB to do the following conversion.

- User access URL: `https://example.com/t/foo.com/common/<something>`
- Proxied by LB: `https://example.com/<something>?t=foo.com`

First of all, is this possible to be done?

I tried the below config but didn't work as expected.

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name example.com;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/example-selfsigned.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/example-selfsigned.key;
    
    location /t/[a-z.]+/common/ {

        rewrite ^(/t/.*)/common/(.*)$ https://192.168.1.3:9443/$2?t=$1 break;

        proxy_pass https://192.168.1.3:9443/;

    }
}
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex matching locations should use `~` (or `~*` for case-insensitive matching) modifiers. You should not add the scheme or domain part to your `rewrite` directive when you want to rewrite an URI that to be proxied with `proxy_pass` directive. Try the following:

```
location ~ ^/t/(?<t>[a-z.]+)/common(?<path>/.*) {
    rewrite ^ $path?t=$t break;
    proxy_pass proxy_pass https://192.168.1.3:9443;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer @Ivan. But I'm getting an error.

`nginx: [emerg] "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except" block in /etc/nginx/conf.d/example.conf:12`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify a `break` flag on the `rewrite` directive, fixed that. You should use exactly the `proxy_pass proxy_pass https://192.168.1.3:9443;` as shown in the answer **without** the trailing slash.